# Updating related rows in list when one changes, or filter in view based on another row

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list-view

I have a document library containing 100's of business cases as well as their related documents. The Content Type is set to "Business Case" for the primary document and to "Supporting Document" for all other related document. Currently only the Business Case itself has all the status and date columns filled in. The default view is grouped by business case ID so the business case and supporting documents (if any) apprear together.

All good to this point. However when trying to filter our business cases in the view that are "closed", the supporting documents still appear because they have no status in them. Any idea how I can either automatically update status of related supporting documents when the business case is closed, or amend the view in such a way that it excludes supporting documents if the related business case is closed?

Cheers - Brett

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Use a event receiver to update the "Document Type" to something else so that it doesn't appear in the View.
2. (Easiest). Just adjust your view by adding a Filter... Example, "Content Type" IS NOT EQUAL TO (Leave the field blank)

Comment: Thanks Fox, 2 is the easiest of course, but yeilds the wrong results because all the supporting documents are blank. Basically I need to update all the related supporting documents status when the primary document status changes. From what I have seen thus far, can't find a way to change column data of another record when one changes. Almost a foreign/primary link within the same list of documents.